# What does "stolen to order" mean?

Tags: meaning

Could you tell me what *stolen or order* mean? For example:

> A few cars has been **stolen to order**.

Comment: Stolen at the request of someone who wanted a particular model of car - like ordering goods from a supplier.

Comment: Should be 'a few cars **have** been stolen'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I once worked in a factory where the staff were suspected of stealing finished goods from the warehouse. The culprit was identified: the police arrested him and searched his house. They were expecting to find most of the stolen goods: instead, they found a display case containing just one of each product that the company made.

Customers visited the culprit's house and placed an order for the items that they wanted, and then he stole the exact type and number of items that the customer had ordered. This was **stealing to order**.